# SSH connection refused on fresh started Ubuntu 14.04. - Connection possible after restart of ssh until reboot

Tags: ssh, openssh, sshd

I'm a newbie to linux and ran into a problem with my new media machine in the living room.

I want to control it over VNC from time to time and therefore installed openssh-server. From the beginning I had troubles connecting from within the local LAN until I found out that simply restarting using:

```
sudo service ssh restart
```

enables me to connect until I restart the machine. After rebooting I have to restart the service and connection is possible...

Trying to start the ssh deamon after (re)boot of the system gives the feedback that it is already running.

Its a fresh install of Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.... anyone having an idea or came across that problem before?

Thanks for your expertise

Jan

---

Additional Info

what I did to document this problem better:

- restart computer
- run command from vembutechs answer
- getting status from ssh (showing no PID)
- connection try -> refused
- restart ssh
- again getting status from ssh (this time showing PID)
- connection attempt -> success

Basically I want ssh simply to accept connections after its been autostarted with ubuntu...   getting rid of the extra ssh restart

And then here is what the output was

```
media@MediaServer:~$ ps -ef | egrep '(ssh|PID)'
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
media     2597  2508  0 22:41 pts/1    00:00:00 egrep --color=auto (ssh|PID)
media@MediaServer:~$ sudo service ssh status
[sudo] password for media: 
ssh start/running
media@MediaServer:~$ ssh media@192.168.178.44
ssh: connect to host 192.168.178.44 port 22: Connection refused
media@MediaServer:~$ sudo service ssh restart
ssh stop/waiting
ssh start/running, process 2628
media@MediaServer:~$ sudo service ssh status
ssh start/running, process 2628
media@MediaServer:~$ ssh media@192.168.178.44
The authenticity of host '192.168.178.44 (192.168.178.44)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is a0:49:e3:1e:f6:56:6b:22:11:9d:e8:fd:cf:7b:66:91.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added '192.168.178.44' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
media@192.168.178.44's password: 
Last login: Thu Jan  8 22:31:14 2015 from janux.fritz.box
stop: Rejected send message, 1 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.97"   (uid=1000 pid=2653 comm="stop ssh ") interface="com.ubuntu.Upstart0_6.Job" member="Stop" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination="com.ubuntu.Upstart" (uid=0 pid=1 comm="/sbin/init")
start: Rejected send message, 1 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.98" (uid=1000 pid=2647 comm="start ssh ") interface="com.ubuntu.Upstart0_6.Job" member="Start" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination="com.ubuntu.Upstart" (uid=0 pid=1 comm="/sbin/init")
media@MediaServer:~$
```

Answer (score 0):

You can terminate the running process

```
ps -ef | egrep '(ssh|PID)'
```

You will get one /usr/sbin/sshd with PID and UID root. This is the listening daemon. All other sshd : user@pts/0 records are user sessions. Look for appropriate session by username and kill the process to terminate this session. Once it is done you can start the ssh process

Comment: Thanks so far, I updated the post with the output of your command and some clarification of the problem...maybe you wanna look into it? Thanks